# Copy one column in elasticsearch index into another column applying analyzers

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, elastic-stack, logstash-jdbc

I am using logstash jdbc plugin to insert data from db to already created custom index in elastic search. I have some columns in the index which are analyzed using custom analyzers.

For example I am getting column1 from database which is not analyzed. I have created two columns column2 and column3 for which analyzers are applied while creating an index. Now I want the same data of column1 to be copied into column2 and column3 while the data is being inserted.

I am using the following pattern while creating index:

```
"mappings": {   
    "itemsnew": {   
        "properties": {   
            "column1": {  
                "type": "string",  
                "copy_to": "column2",   
                "copy_to": "column3"    
            },   
        "column2": {    
            "index_analyzer": "custom analyzer",   
            "search_analyzer": "standard",   
            "type": "string"   
        }    
    }    
}
```

Will the data get inserted into the column2 and column3 and will it be analyzed ?

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: Since you're in control of the client, you might also look into mutlifields (so you can have myField.foo and myField.bar): https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/_multi_fields.html

Comment: I have tried running this but I am not able to see the column2 and column3 as a columns displayed like column1. But when I am able to search data by selecting column2 and column3 in Structured query under match_all. 
1) How to display the columns : column2 and column3
2) How to check if the data is getting analysed or not ?